# Can't understand how virtual address was converted to binary form

Tags: binary, operating-system, virtual-address-space

This is a question and answer from my operating system's textbook:

Question:

```
A certain computer provides its users with a virtual-memory space of 232 bytes. 
The computer has 218 bytes of physical memory. The virtual memory is implemented by paging, 
and the page size is 4096 bytes. A user process generates the virtual address 11123456. 
Explain how the system establishes the corresponding physical location. 
Distinguish between software and hardware operations.
```

Answer:

```
The virtual address in binary form is
0001 0001 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110
```

When I plug "11123456" into a decimal to binary converter (like here: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html), this is the result: 101010011011101100000000

which differs from the book answer.

Also, when I manually convert using a method like here: https://indepth.dev/the-simple-math-behind-decimal-binary-conversion-algorithms/

I still get something different.

I'm just confused how that virtual address was converted into binary form......

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You think

> 11123456

is a ***decimal number*** but it isn't. The Computer representation of number is ever ***binary, octal or hexadecimal***. In this case is Hexadecimal. If you convert the above number from hexadecimal to binary form you obtain the result:

> 0001 0001 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110

Explanation:

```
Hexadecimal -> Binary
      1     ->   0001
      2     ->   0010
      3     ->   0011
      4     ->   0100
      5     ->   0101
      6     ->   0110
           ...
```